# react native iOS: Could not connect to development server

Tags: ios, react-native

I have an issue while debug my app which is build by react native. Whenever i started to build, it gives me error that could not connect to development server. I tried various solutions like upgrading npm, clearing watchman cache, restarting npm. None of them is working. Any help is most welcome!!!

Comment: Try this. Open another terminal and run,  react-native start — reset-cache. Then run, react-native run-android on your current terminal.

Comment: @Ryan94 it's not working. But thank you for suggestion.

Comment: is your device and development computer in the same network? if you browse to http://yourcomputerip:8081/ from your mobile you should see something like: React Native packager is running.
make sure your firewall it's allowing the connection

Answer (score 7):

I know Answer is late. but this works for me everytime.

```
# Clean cache
rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-*; rm -rf $TMPDIR/haste-*; rm -rf $TMPDIR/metro-*; watchman watch-del-all

# Open a new tab and Start Metro Bundler directly from the project folder
react-native start  --reset-cache

# Now run `react-native run-android` or `react-native run-ios`
```

Original [Link](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/21490)

Answer (score 6):

I've got the same issue today (out of the blue). Works like a charm before, but then it doesn't work anymore after I've upgraded react-native to from 0.58.8 to 0.60.5.

I figured out, that I got two network-devices with different IP addresses, if I type `ifconfig` into the Terminal: en0 with an 192.xxx address, and en1 with an 162.xxx Address.

The error at my device show, that it try to connect to the 162.-Address.

After all, I've solved it with a change in `AppDelegate.m`like that:

```
  // Workaround for local IP:
  return [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.178.62:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios"];
  // return [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];
```

Choose your own IP for the http-Address and give it a try.
To check, if you can access the Packager-URL, you also can give it a try in your Browser.